# Proguard Parse Exception Error

Tags: android, proguard

Having a problem getting proguard to work.

If I try to export an unsigned application 
the output console throws the following error on
windows when using eclipse and the latest ADT.

```
Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
proguard.ParseException: Expecting class path separator ';' before 'C:\Users\wolf\workspace\Dcon\lib\joda-time-1.6.2.jar' in argument number 4
at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseClassPathArgument(ConfigurationParser.java:295)
at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parse(ConfigurationParser.java:109)
at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:491)
```

I have done some searching and have found that normally this error comes up when you have a space in the file path, but as you can see their is no space in the path.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: had you set the environment variable?

Comment: Not understanding what you mean. I have turned proguard on by adding into my default.properties file the line proguard.config = proguard.cfg

Comment: i think this link will helpful to you for configuring Proguard http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/07/optimizing-obfuscating-and-shrinking.html may be helpful

Comment: Any information on making this work in eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay found answer on my own. Updating here for others.

Seems it is a problem with the proguard that ships with the adk12.

Link has more details.
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18359

Upgraded to proguard 4.6 and it suddenly started working.
Do NOT change the bat file as suggested that just confused things worse.

Also ended up updating the environment variable PROGUARD manually.

So not sure what exactly fixed the problem but it now works.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I have other solve.

The Proguard official said that reason is your library path contain space.

But I found My library path contain "(" or ")" also cause this dxxn problem.

I am using sdk r12 and ProGuard 4.6.

Hope help.